# Adding hyperlinks into microposts Hartl Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, railstutorial.org

I am trying to make it so that when a user posts a link as a micropost, a user that follows them can simply click on the link and be taken to the website.  Currently the link is just posted as text.  How can I give this property to a micropost?

Here is what my microposts looks like in _feed_item.html.erb

```
    <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
```

This is part of a partial that renders microposts into a newsfeed.  I need this "content" part to become a hyperlink, not just a text string "https:/...."

This is post-Rails Tutorial. Please let me know if any more specific code is needed.  Thanks!

Comment: please post some code to explain what you're doing and what you have so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [rinku](https://github.com/vmg/rinku) or [rails_autolink](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) gems.

According to rinku's github page:

```
require 'rinku'

Rinku.auto_link(text, mode=:all, link_attr=nil, skip_tags=nil)
Rinku.auto_link(text, mode=:all, link_attr=nil, skip_tags=nil) { |link_text| ... }
```

For your use-case I'd try putting the code in a helper.  For example in micro_post_helper.rb:

```
require 'rinku'

module MicroPostHelper
  def add_links(text)
    Rinku.auto_link(text)
  end
end
```

Then in your erb* you can use that helper method.

*Consider switching from erb to haml.

Comment: I added rinku to the gemfile, bundle installed, then put "//=require rinku" in my application.js file.  What else needs to happen in order for it to make my micropost links into hyperlinks?

Comment: Also, I don't think rinku uses JavaScript.

Comment: I saw the content you edited into the answer, I don't know where to put that though if not in application.js. Do I wrap it around "content" in my _feed_item.html.erb partial? (pictured above)

Comment: I added stuff.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I created the helper and it gave me this AbstractController::Helpers::ClassMethods::MissingHelperError in StaticPagesController#home

Comment: Where did you put the file?

Comment: It's probably just a naming thing.  Rename the file to match your model or controller.